# Calling Closure Resulting in Error in Swift

Tags: swift

What I am doing wrong?[image]

I have a closure as you can see in the image. The CellType is declared as ShoppingListTableViewCell in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to try to cast tableView.dequeueReusabeCellWithIdentiffier(..) as ShoppingListTableViewCell instead of CellType.
Are you sure you didn't swap cell and shoppingList ?

Comment: Thanks! All that Lean View Controller stuff and extreme refactoring is making the code hard to read!